# quasicoherent sheaf of ideal defines a closed subscheme

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

I was doing Professor Vakil's FOAG in exercise 9.1 F needs to prove:
that quasicoherent sheaf of ideals on $Y$ produce an closed subscheme on $Y$.

---

Here is my attempt, to construct it locally is not hard, for any $\text{Spec} B \subset Y$ be an open subset, then the section of the ideal sheaf denote as $I(B) = \mathcal{I}(\text{Spec}\ B)$ which is ideal of $B$ therefore we can construct the closed subscheme locally as $\text{Spec } B/ I(B)$.

The problem lies on that they glue together to a global closed subscheme. that is the inclusion $$\text{Spec } B/I(B) \to \text{Spec }B \subset Y\\\text{Spec } A/I(A) \to \text{Spec }A \subset Y$$

has same image on their overlap.

---

I guess this step needs to use the quasicoherent of the ideal sheaf, so that for $\text{Spec} A_f$, the section of the ideal sheaf is $$I(A_f) = (I(A))_f$$ due to quasicoherent of the sheaf. However I have no idea how to preceed then . How to glue them together.

Comment: do you have any properties for $Y$?

if it is not tooooooo crazy, you should actually have already implicitly glued it. The intersection of two affines should be affine again and a localization, so your property tells you that they agree there, so you can just glue it along that, as quotienting out your ideal on the localization gives localization along the quotient.

Comment: @Enkidu , no there is no additional condition on $Y$, and why the intersection of affine is again affine? Can you show more details

Comment: I know why it is true roughly, but has difficulty proving it very clear and precise.

Comment: There must be some assumptions somewhere, your question does not state what Y should be, I assume a scheme, but theoretically, it could also be a stack...
Sorry am lazy and dont want to hunt through Vakil's notes again in chase of the assumptions/standard notation he has in that chapter. They are awesome notes, but also VERY long

Comment: Thank you @Enkidu  .Yes , I only care about the scheme right now, but I have checked that there is no other condition other than being a scheme. I think Vakil's notes is a very good place to learn AG, as for beginner it's important to understand sufficient amount of details, not just the result. When you free, can you write down the detail of the proof for this exercise?

Comment: just wanted to check the precise statement and available tools, as some practice might not hurt me either, but in https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf exercise 9.1.F is vastly different, could it be you have a typo there

Comment: Yeah @Enkidu , Vakil updates his note in 2022, and there is a latest version, you can google the 2022 Aug version note. here : http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGaug2922public.pdf

Comment: merci beaucoup, then I will also update my offline version I have of that! Glad to see he added some derived stuff! Me likey

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144302/discussion-between-enkidu-and-yi-li).

Comment: Hint: Define $Y$ to be the support of the coherent sheaf $\mathcal{O}/\mathcal{I}$, and show that this sheaf of rings makes $Y$ a scheme.

Comment: thank you @Daniel  , I try to follow your hint and only needs to restrict our attention to $Y$ being affine, since checking $\mathcal{O}/\mathcal{I}
$ being a closed subscheme is local, but I have some problem in firguring out what the support of the quotient sheaf really is?

Comment: By support, I mean that the set of points $x$ where $(\mathcal{O}/\mathcal{I})_x \neq 0$. Affine locally, the support of a coherent sheaf $\tilde{M}$ is the closed set $V(\operatorname{Ann}(M))$.

Comment: Oh thank you @Daniel , I got it, first the section quotient sheaf on the distinguished open set is simply the quotient of the section, in particular $\text{Spec } A = Y$ we have $(\mathcal{O}/\mathcal{I}) (Y) = A/I(A)$ since $\mathcal{I}$ is quasicoherent, the quotient is also quasicoherent, therefore the quotient sheaf on $Y$ is just the sheaf associated to  ${A}/{I(A)}$, the support is simply $V(I(A))$ which is the same as $\text{Spec } A/I(A)$.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes! This is what I had in mind.

Comment: Great, thank you Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y$ be covered by $\text{Spec } A_i$ such that $\text{Spec }A_i \cap \text{Spec }A_j$ is covered by some simutanuously distinguished open set, such that $$D_{A_i}(g) = D_{A_j}(f)$$ by the equivalence of the category of affine schemes and category of commutative ring, we have $$(A_i)_g \cong (A_j)_f$$ Also we have $I((A_i)_g) =(I(A_i))_g$ by the quasicoherent of the ideal sheaf. Therefore by the isomorphism of$$I(A_i)_g \cong I(A_j)_f$$ we have $$\text{Spec } (A_i/I(A_i))_g  \cong \text{Spec } (A_j/I(A_j))_f$$

since schemes $\text{Spec } (A_i/I(A_i))$ has an isomorphic open subset say $\text{Spec } (A_i/I(A_i))\cap D_{A_i}(g) \cong \text{Spec } (A_j/I(A_j))\cap D_{A_j}(f)$, by the gluing lemma we can glue them together to a unique scheme, which can be checked to be a closed subscheme by definition.